# Sql combining Strings together

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a datepicker that returns

`$Time: 09:00` (this is string)

`$Date: 2014-05-01` (this is string)

I want to combine them as strings to get this:

`$From: 2014-05-02T09:00:00`

So i need `$From = $Date + 'T' + $Time + ':00'`

Why isn't this working:

```
include 'Db.php';

$dateFrom = '2014-05-02' . 'T' . '09:00' . ':00';
$dateTo = '2014-05-02' . 'T' . '14:00' . ':00';

$con = DbConnect();

$sql = "insert into calendar(ContactName, DateFrom, DateTo, ContactPhone) values ('User', '".$dateFrom."', '".$dateTo."', '1234567' )";

print(json_encode(mysqli_affected_rows($con))); 

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: use `\DateTime()` and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very simple
 you just have to use "." insted of "+"

```
$From = $Date . 'T' . $Time . ':00'
```

Edit:

```
include 'Db.php';

$dateFrom = '2014-05-02' . 'T' . '09:00' . ':00';
$dateTo = '2014-05-02' . 'T' . '14:00' . ':00';

$con = DbConnect();

$sql = "insert into calendar(ContactName, DateFrom, DateTo, ContactPhone) values ('User', '".$dateFrom."', '".$dateTo."', '1234567' )";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

    print(json_encode(mysqli_affected_rows($con))); 

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it stil doesn't want to insert a new row in my table

Comment: @user3392688 you are not inserting `$sql` . `mysqli_query($sql)`

Comment: Got error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in .../test.php on line 10

Line 10 is: if(mysqli_query($sql)){

Comment: @user3392688 opps! just add `$con`.  `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` I have edited the answer